# What is Serializers to_internal_value method used for in Django

Tags: django, rest

I have some models with foreignKey and serializers with a relatedField. But I have an error saying that to_internal_value needs to be implemented first. However, I don't know the use of this method and could not find any useful reference on the web. Any help explaining this is more than appreciated.

Comment: please add the models code to the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To update the foreign fields for a serializer we use `serializer.relatedField` which have two functions: `to_representation` and `to_internal_value`. `to_representation` is used to modify the GET body for your API and `to_internal_value` is used to validate the update request for your serializer, for example, it will help you in checking if the request for updating relatedField is present in the other table or not and things like that.

Let's say we have 2 models. One is `Foo` and the other is `Bar`, and `Foo` is Foreign Key to `Bar`, so we need to write the following serializer to validate and update foreign keys that way.

Here is the code snippet:-

```
class FooField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name,
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            try:
                obj_id = data['id']
                return Obj.objects.get(id=obj_id)
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id is a required field.'
                )
            except ValueError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id must be an integer.'
                )
        except Obj.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'Obj does not exist.'
            )

class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooField(
        queryset=Foo.objects.all()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'd say that the validation should be performed in `validate_<field_name>` methods rather than directly into the `to_internal_value()`. The top level validation should be performed in `validate()` method as well. They are all called by the default implementation of `to_internal_value()`, so the proper use case to override this method is to mutate the data into custom representation.

Comment: @VladRusu can you explain in a bit more detail. I did not completely follow what you are trying to say?

Comment: Is ti possible to create nested without the ObjectRelatedField() rather pass the values in a create() method?

Comment: How then do I use such a field in posting? The two solutions above are for getting and updating, how about creating? Been stuck on that for a while

Comment: Why the `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` methods of `BarSerializer` could not be overriden to achieve all of this?