# How do I add a default value to a nested serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, backend, django-serializer

I am trying to have my "address" API return the default value (empty string ""), but when I use default="" in the serializer field it returns null instead.
This is my main serializer (LocationSerializer)

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    business_id = serializers.PKRelatedField(Business.any.all(), "business")
    city_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=48, required=True)
    tax_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=48)
    phone = serializers.PhoneNumberField()
    address = serializers.CharField()
    address_details = AddressEmbeddedSerializer(default="", source="addresses")
    footer = serializers.CharField()
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    has_kds = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    position = serializers.PointField()
    image = serializers.ImageField()
    # profile = LocationProfileSerializer()
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    payment_methods = PaymentMethodEmbeddedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = (
            "id", "business_id", "city_id", "name", "tax_number", "phone", "address", "address_details", "footer",
            "is_active", "has_kds", "position", "image", "permissions", "payment_methods"
        )
```

and this is my nested serializer (AddressEmbeddedSerializer)

```
class AddressEmbeddedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(default="")
    area = serializers.CharField(default="")
    block = serializers.CharField(default="")
    avenue = serializers.CharField(default="")
    long = serializers.CharField(default="")
    lat = serializers.CharField(default="")

    class Meta:
        model = LocationAddress
        fields = (
            "city", "area", "block", "avenue", "long", "lat"
        )
```

The value that I am expecting is:

```
"address_details": {
            "city": "",
            "area": "",
            "block": "",
            "avenue": "",
            "long": "",
            "lat": ""
        }
```

Instead what I am getting is:

```
"address_details": null
```

Please note that all CRUD operations are working, this is only a default value issue

Comment: It could be possible to implement a renderer to show empty values in a GET request. I wanted the same thing in [csv renderer](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv), achieved it by providing [explicit headers](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv#labeled-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `"address_details": null` is that the current object has no related `addresses` at a model object so the nested serializer won't be accessed and therefore your desired JSON output won't be generated.

Also, `default` is used when no value provided for the field with `POST` request not `GET`

I suggest that you handle `address_details` when it is `null`, but if you really need to do this you can do something at `to_representation()` or `to_internal_value()`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606711/4984493

Also, you can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), so based on `obj.addresses`'s value if it was `null` or not you return the desired JSON output you need.

Comment: thanks! May I ask, what do you mean by "handle `address_details` when it is null?

Comment: like when `address_details ` is null you return the default values with empty strings