# ModelSerializer write with a field and read with other fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I POST to an API and relate the created Bar object to an existing Foo object. I use the name of Foo,
for example:

```
self.client.post('/app/bar/',
                data={
                'username': 'nikko123',
                'foo': 'Nikko'
                },
```

In my Bar Serializer, the Foo field has a ModelSerializer to relate it with,

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('name', 'link')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Get name of Foo
        foo = Foo.objects.get(name=data)
        return {'foo': foo}

    def get_link(self, object):
        print('req', object.id)
        if object.id and request:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(
                '/app/foo/{}'.format(object.id))
        return None


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(source='*')
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

My problem is that the response from Bar, I get empty from Foo.

```
{'id': 2,
'username': 'nikko123',
'foo': {'link': None}, # name is also missing
}
```

I have tested the Bar object and it saved the Foo, however it is not serializing.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: I think that you are missing the `to_representation` method, look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606711/2036767

Comment: That is a FieldSerializer. I think ModelSerializer should do this automatically since name and link were declared.